# how to append local variable from function to array/list in python?

Tags: python

How to append local variable from inside function to array/list in python?
below is my code.

I want to append corr variable to an empty array.
suppose `T=[]` .
its not appending and going in infinite loop.
how can I do this?

```
    # Python Program to find correlation coefficient.
import math
# function that returns correlation coefficient.
def correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n) :
    sum_X = 0
    sum_Y = 0
    sum_XY = 0
    squareSum_X = 0
    squareSum_Y = 0
    i = 0
    while i < n :
        # sum of elements of array X.
        sum_X = sum_X + X[i]
        # sum of elements of array Y.
        sum_Y = sum_Y + Y[i]
        # sum of X[i] * Y[i].
        sum_XY = sum_XY + X[i] * Y[i]
        # sum of square of array elements.
        squareSum_X = squareSum_X + X[i] * X[i]
        squareSum_Y = squareSum_Y + Y[i] * Y[i]
        z = ((float)(math.sqrt((n * squareSum_X -sum_X * sum_X)* (n * squareSum_Y -sum_Y * sum_Y))))
        y = ((float)(n * sum_XY - sum_X * sum_Y))
        i = i + 1
    if z == 0:
        corr = 0
    else:
        # use formula for calculating correlation coefficient.
            corr=abs(y/z)
            while corr<1:
                T=[]
                T.append(corr)
                print("T",T)
            return corr
# Driver function
A = [0,7.6,7.7,6.4,6.25,6.4,6.4,5.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8.3,6.4,3.2,3.2,3.25,3.25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.35,5,4.85,5.65,5.4,5.35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86]
X = [0]*5
Y = [0]*5

#  the size of array.
n=5

# Function call to correlationCoefficient.
k=0
while k <= len(A):
    i = k
    m = 0

    while i <= k+4:
        X[m] = A[i]
        #print("A[i]",A[i])

        Y[m] = B[i]
        #print("B[i]",B[i])
        i = i + 1
        m = m + 1
        #correlationCoefficient(X, Y, 5)
    print ((correlationCoefficient(X, Y, 5)))
    k = k + 1
```

Comment: Please re-format this so it is readable.

Comment: How have you attempted to do this?  `T` isn't even defined any.where.

Comment: i just remeoved it from code

Comment: @SurajNimse If you remove the only relevant part from the code, how are we supposed to help?!

Answer (score 0):

The relevant bit seems to be here:

```
corr=abs(y/z)
while corr<1:
  T=[]
  T.append(corr)
  print("T",T)
return corr
```

You're blanking out the `T` array each time that `while` loop runs, and it will run forever if `corr<1`, since you never change the value of `corr`.

Move `T=[]` outside of the `while i<n` loop if you'd like it to stick around, and modify `corr` (or use an `if` instead) to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: `while corr<1:`
                `T.append(corr)`
                `print("T",T)`
            `return corr`
`# Driver function`
`A = [0,7.6,7.7.......]`
`B = [1,2,3.............]`
`X = [0]*5`
`Y = [0]*5`
`T=[]`

Comment: taken outside but it goes to infinite loop

Comment: @SurajNimse the `while` condition is still true. You're repeating the `append`/`print` operations until `corr>=1`. Since that never happens, you get an infinite loop.